# Why is the radial velocity considered zero?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work

I had recently come across a question which is stated as below:

> A disc placed on a large horizontal floor is connected from a vertical cylinder of radius $r$ fixed on the floor with the help of a light inextensible cord of length $l$ as shown in the figure. Coefficient of friction between the disc and the floor is $\mu$. The disc is given a velocity $v$ parallel to the floor and perpendicular to the cord. How long will the disc slide on the floor before it hits the cylinder?

I thought hard for a few days but I couldn't solve it as the mathematics was terrible. Finally, while trying many other things, I tried considering the radial component of velocity to be zero and it worked! I got the answer.

But I am not able to understand the logic behind considering the radial velocity zero. Would someone please help me to understand it?

Edit: The figure is given as below:

[image: Figure]

Comment: If the radial velocity were zero, the disk would never move closer to the cylinder.

Comment: Where is “the figure” that the problem mentions?

Comment: The cord is winding in around the cylinder. It will spiral in like a tether ball until it hits the pole. Start out with finding the length of the cord at time t.

Comment: Can you show that fig that mentions in the question?

Comment: @sakurashinken I have already solved it, I wanted to know the physics behind considering the radial velocity negligible.

Comment: @YoungKindaichi I have attached the figure now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the disk has got a non-zero radial velocity. This then has $2$ possibilities. First, the radial velocity is outward along the string and second, the radial velocity is inward along the string.

The First case cannot happen because of the restriction given in the question, the string is inextensible.

For the Second case, if the disk has a velocity inward along the length of the string, the string will slacken after the disk moves a distance $dl$ which will then lead to the tension force, the force exerted by the string and the only force that can provide a angular motion to the disk to instantaneously become zero. So, in this case, the disk will keep moving in the same direction with decreasing speed until the string tightens again to start providing a angular motion.

Comment: Wow, this is impressive! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Because the cord is inextensible, its tension does no work on the disc (in other words, the disc always moves perpendicular to the cord). Therefore we can model the situation as a linear deceleration under friction. It would be the same if the cylinder's radius were zero and the motion were circular.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But as the thread gets wound up, the radius changes over time. So how can we be sure that the disc moves perpendicular to the thread? Mathematically, $R=l-rA$, where $A$ is the angle wound, $R$ is the instantaneous radius. So, $dR/dt=-rw$, where $w$ is the angular velocity and the tangential velocity is $Rw$. So the ratio turns out to be $-r/R$, a finite number.

Comment: The radius changes, but the thread is not radially oriented, and like I said, the motion can never be such that it would stretch the thread, so it must be perpendicular to it (or oriented inward along the thread, but there is no force that works to accelerate it more inward than perpendicular)

Comment: Thank you very much! But unfortunately I can accept only one answer.

Comment: This is the correct answer, I think.

Comment: It’s strange that the thread is decreasing in length yet there is no radial velocity. Very strange but that’s what it appears to be.

Comment: There is radial velocity. There is no velocity along the direction of the thread, but they are not the same, that's the thing.

Answer (score 1):

Some commentators also seem to have fallen into the ambiguity of Radial velocity. Radial normally means toward a centre. and a fixed centre. as the string wraps around the cylinder clearly there is no obvious centre as the  motion isn’t circular but some weird spiral and the straight part of string doesn’t continually point back toward a constant common centre. There’s no centre to have radii properly. If the string is unstretchable and doesn’t go slack then however we can say the ball motion is perpendicular to the string along its momentary straight length(which we may try to call radius even though it’s changing centre. Anyway the motion is sort of circular instantaneously about the contact point of string with cylinder which must lead to answer.

Comment: Maybe it could be approximated by rotating around a square... maybe with sides of length $\frac{2\pi r}{4}$

Answer (score 0):

**newest edits in bold.**

***This is the approximate path consistent with slowing down under friction:***

$x(t)=\frac{v_0}{\mu} (1-e^{-\mu t})$

***Because this is the solution to*** $\frac{dx}{dt}=-\mu \frac{dx^2}{dt^2}$.

$ \rightarrow \text{distance traveled along the arclength of the spiral}=\frac{L^2}{2R}$

***Therefore,***

$\frac{v_0}{\mu} (1-e^{-\mu t}) = \frac{L^2}{2R}$

$\text{Solve for t.}$

---

**New Addition:**

$$\begin{eqnarray}
x(\omega t) & = & R \sin(\omega t) + (L - R \omega t) \cos(\omega t)\\
y(\omega t) & = & -R \cos(\omega t) + (L - R \omega t) \sin(\omega t)
\end{eqnarray}$$

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\dot{x}(\omega t) & = & +\omega R \cos(\omega t) - L \omega\sin(\omega t) -R\omega cos(\omega t)+R\omega^2 t sin(\omega t)\\
\dot{y}(\omega t) & = & \omega R \sin(\omega t) + L \omega \cos(\omega t) -R\omega sin(\omega t)-R\omega^2 t cos(\omega t)\\
\end{eqnarray}$$

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\dot{x}(0) & = & 0 \\
\dot{y}(0) & = &  L \omega -R\omega^2 t(0) \\
\end{eqnarray}$$

where $t(0)=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I think the answer given is different.

Comment: The answer depends on $r$. I don't know how to type it in latex format. In your answer, if we make μ tend to zero the time required is infinity which is incorrect.

Comment: While doing the force analysis on the disc, you have missed the tension force that will be applied by the string on the disk

Comment: I don't think that the distance traveled will be l. It's actually the arc length of.a spiral.

Comment: Actually the axis of rotation of the disk is not about the centre of the cylinder. The axis will be about the point where the string loses its contact with the cylinder and as the string winds up more and more on  the cylinder, this axis will keep moving in a circular path along the circumference of the cylinder. The distance of the point from its axis of rotation will be _l_ at the start but will reduce to a zero as the motions comes to an end, or as the disk approaches the cylinder